# Getting a Storage file and copying to another storage place

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have storage files saved and can access them like this:

```
$file = Storage::disk('public')->url("featured/{$i->image}")
```

That nets me the full url of the file I have in my `storage/` directory. How can I make it so that can copy and paste that same exact file into a new directory but with a new file name?

I have tried:

```
$url = Storage::disk('public')->url("featured/{$i->image}");
$fileName = 'u_' . (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp() . '.png';
$fileDestination = '/new_folder/' . $fileName;
$i->image = $fileDestination;
File::copy($url, $fileDestination);
```

I am getting PHP execution timeout errors. I don't think I am referencing the paths correctly.

I want to copy `/storage/app/public/featured/imageOne.png` to `/storage/app/public/new_folder/imageOneWITHNEWFILENAME.png`

Is there a `Storage` facade solution?

Comment: _"But I keep getting errors."_ Such as?

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Please show value of the `$newDestination` variable

Comment: Storage::copy($file, $newDestination); Check this  link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: I have updated it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Storage` facade instead of `File::copy` to copy file to the new destination like

```
Storage::disk('public')->copy("featured/{$i->image}", $fileDestination);
```

Reference: [Laravel 5.5 file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: Getting `File not found at path` even though I KNOW its there.  Inside `storage/app/public`. My `env` `APP_URL` is : `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: And this seems to be copying as if the root were `/public/featured` which is not what I'd like. Trying to figure out a way here... appreciate this.

Comment: Ah, wait I got it working. I see what you mean. Thank you.